# Firebase analytics for iOS Today extension(widget extension)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, today-extension

I tried to add firebase analytics in today extension.
So I input the configuration code

```
if (![FIRApp defaultApp]) {     
  [FIRApp configure];
}
```

in today extension's viewDidLoad.

And in the Xcode's Product > scheme > Edit scheme > Run > Arguments tab, I added the '-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled' as I want to show the logged event in firebase console's DebugView page. But, Any events didn't printed in the page.

The log added into App (not today extension) is checked in the DebugView in real time. What should I do to show today extension's log in firebase DebugView in real time?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, you can't use the app argument on the extension. I could add break point in the extension but I could see that the flag didn't have any effect on the extension. Therefore, extensions cannot send data in debug mode for now.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked that the events occurred in app extension has been logged on firebase -> console's 'event' tab. I think it doesn't support real-time debug view for extension. In 3~4 hours later, event is checked. Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from code by calling **setLoggerLevel** method on **FirebaseConfiguration** singleton and set the logger level.
please see Firebase analytics documentation :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes

> Enable debug mode by passing the -FIRDebugEnabled argument to the
>   application. You can add this argument in the application’s Xcode
>   scheme. When debug mode is enabled via -FIRDebugEnabled, further
>   executions of the application will also be in debug mode. In order to
>   return to default mode, you must explicitly disable the debug mode
>   with the application argument -FIRDebugDisabled.
>
> It is also possible to change the default logging level in code by
>   calling setLoggerLevel: on the FIRConfiguration interface.